# Não está funcionando o ícone

Tags: css, icons

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/ProjetosVO.php';
require_once 'Classes/ProjetosDAO.php';

$objBDProjeto=new ProjetosDAO();
$objProjeto= new ProjetosVO();

$rsProjeto= $objBDProjeto->ListarProjetos("1");
$tblProjeto= mysqli_fetch_array($rsProjeto);
?>
<style>
.pasta input[type=radio]{
   display: none;
}.pasta label i.fa:before{
   content: '\f0f4';
   color: #0062cc;
}.pasta  input[type=radio]:checked  ~ label i.fa:before{
   color: #c6c8ca;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous">      </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eb2dfeaa2c.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<center><h1 class="Titulo">Meus Projetos</h1></center>
<div class="pasta">
   <br>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <?php
   $numero=mysqli_num_rows($rsProjeto);
   $i=1;

   while($tblProjeto= mysqli_fetch_array($rsProjeto)){ 
   ?>
   <h1><i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>

   <?php
      $projeto=$tblProjeto['nome_PROJETO'];
      echo $projeto;
   ?>
   <br>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <?php
   }
   ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar a tag de css do Font Awesome. Basta colocar o seguinte código.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Ou então você pode baixar o mesmo pelo site: http://fontawesome.io e adicionar ele na sua pasta local. Caso você tenha baixado basta adicionar a tag abaixo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="caminho/para/seu/arquivo/font-awesome.min.css">
```